# iOS 11 Ringtone for No Caller ID

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, ringtones, caller-id

Is there any way (even a brute-force workaround) to assign a unique ringtone to "No Caller ID"?

**Manually assigning a ringtone to all contacts and setting the default ringtone to something different is not an acceptable solution to the problem**, because both unknown callers and *No Caller ID* callers will use the default ringtone.  I would like a ringtone that's unique specifically for *No Caller ID*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following is an old trick, I don't know if it's still working :

- Create a new contact called something like Non-Caller or No-Caller
- Enter 000-000-0000 for the phone number.
- Assign your unique ringtone or/and block it

src: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6040239

Personally, I'm using the **Truecaller** app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/truecaller/id448142450?mt=8

Comment: This does not work in iOS 12. Is there a workaround for that?