# How to block "No Caller ID" calls but not unknown calls

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, caller-id

My phone number is published on the website of a project I run. However, it seems some young people have found it really funny to start prank calling me. It's very annoying and rather humiliating to have them get a laugh out of me at my expense. I would like to block them.

The conventional advice is to enable "Silence Unknown callers" in iOS 13. However, this will block not only Unknown Caller ID but also any number not in contacts. This doesn't work for me, because as a part of the project, strangers will contact me by calling which I do want.

Is there any way to *only* block private numbers/"No Caller ID" in iOS without also blocking people that are not in contacts? It doesn't seem like a hard problem since one can easily tell if it is a number or if it is unknown but I can't figure it out. I've tried the [000-000-0000 trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321970/ios-11-ringtone-for-no-caller-id) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain it's not currently possible in iOS, but your cell carrier may have this option.